# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriterException: Unsupported type from web api

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Please help me out , While returning Model to jsonObject I am getting the error below

**Unsupported type: ExperienceAPI.Models.VarNumberResponse . Use the JsonSerializer class to get the object's JSON representation. Path ''.**

however when I am using

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(varNumberResponse)
```

it returning the response as string but I want it to be return as object below is my full code.

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context) {

    VarNumberResponse varNumberResponse = GetVarNumberResponse(); // Getting data from data base
    UserDetail userDetail = GetUserDetail(); // Getting data from data base

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary) {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(AgentExperience.STATUS, AgentExperience.OK);
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("varNoResponse", varNumberResponse);
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("userDetail",userDetail);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the `VarNumberResponse` class and the example output of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(varNumberResponse)`

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(varNumberResponse) Result

"varNoResponse": "{\"Code\":\"50w6042895\",\"LastDataRefresh\":\"201802260615\",\"Reason\":\"VALID\",\"CardholderName\":\"Example \",\"CardExpiryDate\":\"00-00-YYYY\",\"AgencyCode\":\"9A230AQEW0045\",\"AgencyName\":\"TEST LIMITED\"}",